# Read a text file and return a following string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to parse a text document using VBA and return a string of variable length following a key phrase so that it appears in a new row in a column. The text file would look something like this:

```
lourum ipsum dolor sit amet
  Name : John Doe Phone : DOB : 01/01/2000 (20 yrs) Sex : Male 
lourum ipsum dolor sit amet 
  Name : Jane Doe Phone : xxx-xxx-xxxx DOB : 01/01/2000 (20 yrs) Sex : Female
```

I want the VBA to search the entire document for all occurrences of a field (like "Sex : ") and return either male or female, then write each occurrence to a new cell, say `A2` for the first, `A3` for the next, etc.

My main questions would be:
1. How can I skip lines that leave a field empty (like in line 2 `Phone :`)?
2. How can I include the fields of varying length (Male/Female)?

Edit: I was able to use the Mid function to get the desired result in a small test file, however when using it with the larger real file it gives an "invalid procedure call or argument" error. I've included the code here:

```
Sub Test_Code()


 Dim strMain As String
 Dim Age As String
 Dim AgeLocation As Long
 Dim R As Long
 R = 2 
Open "F:\Common\Example.txt" For Input As #1 ' Open file.
Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    Line Input #1, strMain ' Read line into variable.
    If InStr(strMain, "DOB :") Then
    AgeLocation = InStr(1, strMain, "yrs")
    AgeLocation = AgeLocation - 3
    Age = Mid(strMain, AgeLocation, 2)
    Range("A" & R).Value = (Age)
    R = R + 1

    End If


Loop
Close #1 ' Close file.
End Sub
```

If anyone has any feedback it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read each line, check it for an occurrence of the string you are looking for using `Instr`, if found, `Split` it using `:` and then check each item in the result array.

Comment: Once you use that idea to create some code, you can include it in your question and explain where you ran into trouble.

Comment: I'm pretty inexperienced so I wasn't quite sure how to incorporate the split function, however I did come up with a different approach using the Mid function: